# Email Configuration Settings not being fetched

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, winforms, email

I have application that fetches email configuration settings such as host (SMTP Server name), username (SMTP Username) and Password from App.Config File as shown below

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="name@example.com"><network host="smtp.gmail.com" userName="test123@gmail.com" port="25" password="PassworD"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Now i wish to configure the settings that i have set in database and NOT from App.Config File. From database the credentials are not available in SMTPClient's properties .FYI, they are saved in database as well as the values are also correct.

Please Help!

Thanks

Comment: So what do you want to do, you kinda lost me there in the end. Please edit your question and clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Instead of Settings coming from app.config, i have saved this settings in database. But when i see the SMTPClient properties, all the values are coming to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate the [SMTPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) just set the values specifically there. This overrides the settings from your app.config/web.config file.

```
  var msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("from@yoursite.com", "to@somesite.com", "Subject", "Body text...");
  var c = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 25);
  c.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("test123@gmail.com", "PassworD");
  c.Send(msg);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment!. But do i need to set this whenever i need to write code to send an email?

Comment: Yeah, you need to override the default settings this way. But I don't think that should be much of an issue, after all it's only a few lines of code extra. Wrap it in a method and you're good to go. :)

Answer (score 0):

when you were using the web.config version the settings were automatically filled in for you. Now as you have saved it in DB, you need to specify the settings.